# Bengali font not working in Libre-office or any text editor applications in MX-Linux kde

Tags: fonts, libreoffice, mx-linux

I have installed open-bangla keyboard to type in Bengali in my system. Though I can type in Bengali in the web browsers and also in skype app(which is installed), I cannot do the same in any other apps in my system, like LibreOffice writer, text-editor like kate or gedit. I have switched to Bengali input, but whatever type is plain English. I have installed Noto Sans Bengali font in my system and it is working fine in the browsers, but I am clueless about the fact that why I cannot type in Bangla in other software or applications.

Looking for a solution, I have followed this [link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/875248/bangla-fonts-not-working-in-libreoffice), but it did not work out.

Can anyone help me with this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To do that, I had to select the default input method to be ibus. I ran im-config from the terminal and select ibus as the default input method. After a restart, I could write Bengali on any editor software.